# Can an instance of IIS not running in a container point at applications which are running in containers?

Tags: docker, iis, docker-desktop

Currently I have an IIS configuration that points to many APIs/Websites which are not containerized.

I would like to slowly begin packaging these applications into containers over time, without disrupting the current behavior of the system.

Is it possible to instruct IIS that a certain route on the server should direct traffic to a given container?

For example, I have a container (linux container) which contains an ASP.NET Core API, and I would like requests made to iis.domain.com/CoreAPI to be sent to that container.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: This seems really outdated, but at least it tells me it should be possible. None of the gui images are up to date with newer versions of IIS unfortunately.

Comment: Got it working, thanks @LexLi!